# How to find element by type in c# webdriver?

Tags: c#, xpath, webdriver

I want to locate and click element by type, how can I do that?

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[type()='submit']")).Click();

<button class="btn btn-default" value="Filtruoti" type="submit" title="Filtruoti" data-init-filter="" data-init="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should filter by attributes using `@attribute='value'` in xpath.

Change it to

```
By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")
```